# How to retrieve data from database using nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am using VS 2010, SQL 2008 with nhibernate to perform database operations.

I know that we can use hbm.xml file to join 2 or more tables. I want to know how to make use of this file in retrieving the data by using the joins specified in this file?

Pls help me. Or any link which gives me info on this.

Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to read over the [nhibernate documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/index.html).  The first few sections give a rough overview of how hbm files map to POCOs (objects) and your database.

You should also read the [Getting Started Guide](http://nhibernate.info/doc/tutorials/first-nh-app/your-first-nhibernate-based-application) on nhibernate.info. These will answer your somewhat vague question above.